# How can I emulate WHERE 1 in a dynamic query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, dynamicquery

I'm making a query dynamically like this:

```
$query = "SELECT u.*
          FROM users u
          WHERE date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 $range))";
```

Also `$range` contains a word like this:

```
switch ($_GET['range']){
   case "week":
      $range = "WEEK";
   case "month":
      $range = "MONTH";
   case "year":
      $range = "YEAR";
   case "ALL":
      $range = <I don't know what should I put here to get the expected result>;
}
```

As I've said above, I want to set something as `$range` value to make  the `WHERE` clause something like `WHERE 1`. How can I do that?

Comment: How about put the whole part of the range part in the switch and not put it in in there if it isn't needed?

Comment: @AdamForbis I use `$range` somewhere else too. I cannot do what you've suggested.

Comment: ^ agreed. Also a good scenario for having some framework/ORM support. You could then maybe have an API for manipulating a SQL statement. e.g. `$query->addWhere()`... Otherwise the string concatenation can get messy fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what Adam was suggesting is something like this:

```
$where = '';

switch ($_GET['range']) {

    case "week":
       $where = "date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK))":
        break;

    case "month":
       $where = "date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))":
        break;

    case "year":
       $where = "date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))":
        break;

    default:
        $where = '';
}

$query = "SELECT u.* FROM users u WHERE $where";
```

Assume reporting with other criteria? Where the string concatenation gets messy. Adding 'AND' between parts. Suppressing WHERE keyword entirely?  Where OOP code to represent the SQL query can be useful.

Comment: `$where = '';` and `WHERE $where` won't work this way. `$where = '1=1'` would do.

Comment: Yup. See last paragraph. Agreed `1=1` is a simple way to deal with it.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps use a case statement in your where clause?

```
 $query = "SELECT u.*
           FROM users u
           WHERE CASE {$range}
                 WHEN 'ALL' then TRUE
                 ELSE date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now()
                                  , INTERVAL 1 {$range}))
                 END";
```

Comment: You understand that the string rendered, will not show `$range` but the value of it?  Also, [syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45469600/how-to-use-case-when-in-the-where-clause) is probably need of `$range` to be in quotes. String to string comparison.

Answer (score 2):

```
switch ($_GET['range']){
  case "week":
  $range = "WEEK";
 case "month":
  $range = "MONTH";
 case "year":
  $range = "YEAR";
 case "ALL":
  $range = null;
}

$query = "SELECT u.*
      FROM users u
      WHERE 1=1 ";
if(!empty($range)) {
  $query .= " AND date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 $range))";
}
```

Add datetime where clause conditionally; `WHERE 1=1` will always be true. So the next condition's result will matter on the final result

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the fact that your switch statement doesn't have break statements and isn't going to work the way you expect.

Here is what I'd suggest:

```
$query = "SELECT u.*
          FROM users u";

$range = false;

if (isset($_GET['range'])) {    
    switch ($_GET['range']){
       case "week":
          $range = "WEEK";
          break;
       case "month":
          $range = "MONTH";
          break;
       case "year":
          $range = "YEAR";
          break;
       default:
          $range = false;
    }
} 


if ($range) {
  $query .= " WHERE date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 $range))";
}
```

Comment: Good observation on missing `breaks` :) How does MySQL handle `INTERVAL 1 _` though?

Comment: If $range is not set, the WHERE clause doesn't get added to the query at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would define an array with valid ranges and validate the user input first. Then build the query dynamicly.

```php
$validRanges = [
    'year'  => 'YEAR',
    'month' => 'MONTH',
    'week'  => 'WEEK',
    'ALL'   => null
];

if (isset($_GET['range']) && !isset($validRanges[$_GET['range']])) {
    $range = $validRanges[$_GET['range']]);
} else {
    // it's up to you, what to do in this case
    throw new Exception('Range is not valid or missing');
}

if ($range === null) {
    $rangeCondition = '1=1';
} else {
    $rangeCondition = "date_time > unix_timestamp(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 $range)";
}

$query = "SELECT u.*
          FROM users u
          WHERE $rangeCondition";
```