# How to use CASE WHEN in the WHERE clause?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Here is a part of my query:

```
WHERE CASE $range WHEN 'ALL' THEN TRUE
      ELSE $this->table_alias.date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 $range))
      END
```

Noted that `$range` is a php variable which contains a word. It throws this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALL WHEN 'ALL' THEN TRUE ELSE re.date_time > unix_timestam' at line 13 in C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\others\users.php:120 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\others\users.php(120): PDO->prepare('SELECT u.id use...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\others\questions.php(359): users->index(' AND categories...', ' INNER JOIN qan...', 'tagged') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\others\users.php(26): questions->tagged('index') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\application\other.php(24): users->index() #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\index.php(161): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\others\users.php on line 120

Does anybody what's wrong?

Comment: Perhaps pursue this on the already open question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45468750/how-can-i-emulate-where-1-in-a-dynamic-query/45468934#45468934

Comment: $range is not quoted and is comparing to 'ALL'.  There is most likely no column named ALL in the table.

Comment: What is `$range`? that supposed to be PHP variable?  Doesn't seem to be a MySQL variable. T Gray, he is trying to do a string to string comparison.

Comment: That case statement doesn't make sense.. What's wrong with the answer by @ficuscr on your other question?

Comment: @ficuscr As I've mentioned in the question `$range` is a PHP variable. So the final query looks like `WHERE CASE ALL WHEN ALL THEN ...`.

Comment: @AaronDietz Seems I have to go with it.

Comment: @stack see my comments on other post too. `'ALL' = 'ALL'` vs `ALL = 'ALL'`.

Comment: Maybe from question 1 `$query = "SELECT u.* FROM users u"; $query .= in_array($_GET['range'], array('week', 'month', 'year')) ? ' WHERE date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 ' . $_GET['range'] . '))';`. I've not seen a `case` used in a `where`.

Comment: I see that he is trying to do a string to string comparison, but the sql interpreter is reading an unquoted string as a column name.

Comment: Note that for MySQL this statement (when fixed) is constant. However it's still possible that you will lose the ability to use an index.

Answer (score 1):

I think you used wrong syntax

```
$sql = "WHERE CASE 
    WHEN '{$range}' = 'ALL' THEN 1=1
    ELSE {$this->table_alias}.date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 $range))
  END";
```

Comment: What is `$range`?... `$sql = "WHERE CASE WHEN {$range}...` maybe... note PHP tags and see previous question in this series.

Comment: i think , it is  php variable

Comment: Agreed.  Not sure that is understood though.

Comment: Thsis syntax has the same problem.

Comment: Cleaned it up some.

Comment: @vjytiwari tested on MySQL and can verify that is now valid syntax.